# Dismiss tip with EasyTipView swift library

Tags: ios, swift, popover

I have been using the EasyTipView swift library for a couple of days, however i am not able to make a particular tip dismiss, i can only make the tip disappear if i tap on it.

This is my sample code:

```
 // Mostramos el tooltip al usuario
EasyTipView.show(forItem: self.buttonRefresh, text: "Refresh Button Tip".localized)
```

The tip will appear below the "buttonRefresh" element in my navigation bar, what i would like to accomplish is that tapping on that same button, the tip disappears.

You can find the library here: https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView

Thanks in advance
Alex

Answer (score 1):

EasyTipView has a member function called dismiss. But to be able to use that you need to have an EasyTipView member variable in your class.
Once you have that , you can call dismiss to remove the EasyTipView window.

```
var easyTipView : EasyTipView!

...
...
func handleRefresh()
{
  if self.easyTipView == nil
  {
    self.easyTipView = EasyTipView(text: "Hello There")
    self.easyTipView.show(animated: true, forView: self.buttonRefresh!, withinSuperView: nil)
  }
  else
  {
    self.easyTipView.dismiss()
    self.easyTipView = nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can do something like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
   self.tipView?.dismiss()
   self.tipView = nil
}
```